# Xamarin Security-Sensitive data storing

Tags: security, xamarin, connection-string, appsettings, sensitive-data

On xamarin app,
where I can store my dbConnection or other security-sensitive data.
For example in asp net application my DBConnection string i store in the appsettings.json file, and a user don't have access to that file.
But on xamarin app I don't found secure way,
For example, I can hardcode dbConnection  in my code, but the user can decompile my code and get dbConnection  string

Comment: check please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69199278/manage-user-secrets-in-a-custom-config-file

Answer (score -1):

You can use SecureStorage from Xamarin Essentials to store sensitive data.

```
await SecureStorage.SetAsync("oauth_token", "secret-oauth-token-value");
```

Check documentation for Xamarin Essentials
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=ios

Comment: But if i will use this code await Secure Storage.SetAsync("oauth token", "secret-oauth-token-value"); the user can open my application on decompiler, an see the secret-oauth-token-value

Comment: dont hard code it. You can generate a GUID the store the value.